Why does blender put large meshes instead of bones when importing a model with bones

I have already tried to change these bones, but only the bones change in edit mode, and there you will not be able to change the pose, only the position and size of the bones

That might be custom shapes, see my answer below. If this is not the solution, we might need your file for further investigation.

It looks like the bones have a Custom Shape applied to them. To change that, go into Pose Mode and select all bones with A.
Then go to the Bone properties tab and under Viewport Display you will find the option Custom Shape. The name which is entered there as Custom Object is the one which is used as shape. To get rid of it, hold the Alt key and click on the $\times$ to remove it (holding Alt is important to remove it from all selected bones at once, otherwise you will only remove the shape from the active bone).

By the way, if you do not want to remove the custom shape (perhaps if you have created your own, you can also give each single bone an individual shape) but just want to disable visibility temporarily or permanently, you can go to the armature's Data properties tab and there under Viewport Display disable the Shapes option.
As the Viewport Display category in both menus indicates, these shapes are only visible in the viewport. Like all armatures they will not be rendered.

